# Cumulative sum based on a condition but reset after condition ends

Tags: r, grouping, cumulative-sum

How do I improve the performance of a cumulative sum reset on condition?

I have a `data.frame` with a demo dataset attached below variable name `demo`.   I have a column with `flag` that states the system fails and then the column `continuousfailure` which counts how many times in succession the failure occurs and resets once it's back.  I'm using tidyverse packages and also base R.

I've been reading through some StackOverflow posts regarding this problem but I just can't seem to wrap my head around a solution that's faster using tidyverse and/or base R.  I've implemented a version of this using a for loop but the computing time is taking way too long for larger datasets (9 minutes for a 107388 row dataframe).  Is there a more efficient solution to this problem?

Test Dataset:

```
demo <- data.frame(data = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 2000), flag = c(rep(FALSE, 5), rep(TRUE, 10), rep(FALSE, 25), rep(TRUE, 23), rep(FALSE, 13), rep(TRUE, 5), rep(FALSE, 19)),
continuousfailure = c(rep(0, 5), 1:10, rep(0, 25), 1:23, rep(0, 13), 1:5, rep(0, 19)),magnitude = NA)
```

The code I'm currently using is:

```
for(i in 1:length(demo$data)) {
  if(demo$flag[i]) {
    bin <- 0
    for(j in 1:demo$continuousfailure[i]) {
      bin <- bin + demo$data[i - j + 1]
    }
    demo$magnitude[i] <- bin
  }
}
```

The expected output is expected to be the same but using tidyverse or base R that would improve the speed of the function would be greatly appreciated also with a bit of an explanation of how the logic was constructed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table` `rleid` to create groups and return `cumsum` or `NA` based on `flag`

```
library(dplyr)

demo %>%
  group_by(group = data.table::rleid(flag)) %>%
  mutate(new_mag = if(first(flag)) cumsum(data) else NA) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-group)

#     data flag  continuousfailure magnitude new_mag
#    <dbl> <lgl>             <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 -1121. FALSE                 0       NA      NA 
# 2  -460. FALSE                 0       NA      NA 
# 3  3117. FALSE                 0       NA      NA 
# 4   141. FALSE                 0       NA      NA 
# 5   259. FALSE                 0       NA      NA 
# 6  3430. TRUE                  1     3430.   3430.
# 7   922. TRUE                  2     4352.   4352.
# 8 -2530. TRUE                  3     1822.   1822.
# 9 -1374. TRUE                  4      448.    448.
#10  -891. TRUE                  5     -443.   -443.
# … with 90 more rows
```

where `magnitude` is the column with value from `for` loop and `new_mag` is the output from the code above.

---

There are multiple ways to create groups. One is as shown above using `rleid`, other is using `lag` from `dplyr` and `cumsum`

```
group_by(group = cumsum(flag != lag(flag, default = first(flag)))) %>%
```

and another one with `base` `rle`

```
group_by(group = with(rle(flag), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)))
```

You could replace the `group_by` line with any of the above.

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
demo <- data.frame(data = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 2000), 
flag = c(rep(FALSE, 5), rep(TRUE, 10), rep(FALSE, 25), rep(TRUE, 23),rep(FALSE, 13),
rep(TRUE, 5), rep(FALSE, 19)),continuousfailure = c(rep(0, 5), 1:10, rep(0, 25), 
1:23, rep(0, 13), 1:5, rep(0, 19)),magnitude = NA)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This does the trick and is very responsive.  I really appreciate the `data.table` package-less solution using dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(demo)[,   new := if(first(flag)) cumsum(data) else NA_real_, rleid(flag)]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
demo <- data.frame(data = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 2000), 
flag = c(rep(FALSE, 5), rep(TRUE, 10), rep(FALSE, 25), rep(TRUE, 23),rep(FALSE, 13),
rep(TRUE, 5), rep(FALSE, 19)),continuousfailure = c(rep(0, 5), 1:10, rep(0, 25), 
1:23, rep(0, 13), 1:5, rep(0, 19)),magnitude = NA)
```